# cellForRowAtIndexPath not called but numberofRowsInSection called for UITableView added as subview to UIView

Tags: ios

I have created custom alert view where i want to add the `UITableView` as subview.I haven't created `UITableView` through `(IB)` but created programmatically,Also I have implement protocol `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` in `UIView`.But the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` not called.
I think the problem is here i have to create `UITableView` through IB make it visible.is it possible not to create through `IB` but using below code and implement the delegate methods.

Here is the code

```
        privacy_tableview = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, alert_width-40.0, 0.0)];                          [privacy_tableview sizeToFit];
        privacy_tableview.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, alert_width-40.0, privacy_tableview.frame.size.height);

       //Add scrollview which contain uitableview
        MsgScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, alert_height, alert_width-20.0, (privacy_tableview.frame.size.height>max_msg_height)?max_msg_height:privacy_tableview.frame.size.height)];

        [privacy_tableview setDataSource:self];
        [privacy_tableview setDelegate:self];

        [privacy_tableview reloadData];
```

Comment: Have u added privacy_tableview as subview?

Comment: where did u add tableview to scrollview?

Comment: just below of above code

Comment: [privacy_tableview reloadData];
            
            MsgScrollView.contentSize = privacy_tableview.frame.size;
            [MsgScrollView addSubview:privacy_tableview];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The height of the table is zero privacy_tableview.frame.size.height = 0.0 and according to table view programming basics for iOS, only visible cells are created and shown in table.

So, increasing the height to at least a row's height could call cellForRowAtIndexPath method of the TableView.

Comment: Updated Code privacy_tableview = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, alert_width-40.0, 80.0)];

Comment: have you added the table view in scroll view and scroll view on your custom alert view?

Comment: also the y origin of your message scroll view starts from the height of the alert view. Suppose the height of the alert view is 100. then the y origin of scroll view would be 100, in this case the scroll view will be added outside the visible height of the alert view

Comment: I have already all these scenario,but cellforrowatindexpath not gets called.

Comment: I think the problem is with uitableview not created through IB.But i have to create it programmatically

Comment: thanks sanjay. update code  privacy_tableview = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, alert_width-10, 100)];
            privacy_tableview.delegate = self;
            privacy_tableview.dataSource = self;